How was Lemech allowed to hunt?
The Midrash Tanchuma (11:2) says that Lemech accidentally killed Kayin while hunting for animals.
Question: wasn’t it forbidden to kill animals before the Mabul (Sanhedrin 59b; see also Tosafot on Sanhedrin 56b, ד״ה אכל תאכל)?
If the answer is simply that it really was forbidden for him to hunt, and yet he did so anyways, then why don’t we find that his wives rebuked him for doing so, like they did regarding his accidental murder of Kayin.

Why do you assume he was allowed to?

@dude read the whole question..

Why do you assume that his wives rebuking him from killing a person is a proof about not being able to hunt? Why should they necessarily be against killing an animal just bc they were against killing a person?

The Gemara Sanhedrin (59b) only says until Noach people were not allowed to kill animal for consumption; however it would be permitted to kill animals for other needs (i.e., warm coat, soft blanket, etc.) see Aruch Laner here.
